# Again, R.java not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have a lot of java files in my project so I decided to create packages and organize those files. After putting them in seperate packages like

```
com.myproject.android.activity
com.myproject.android.adapter
etc...
```

eclipse wants me to import the R file. From different SO questions I know "Never import the R file". However without that eclipse shows error messages that R.java is missing and wants to import it.

I already did a eclipse restart, clean, and android->fix  with no success. My resource files are without errors. Is it safe to import the R file. Any suggestions?

Comment: need to `import packagename.R.;` If R.java is not generated under your gen folder most likely you have errors in your resource files

Comment: @Raghunandan nop no errors in xml files. So I need to import the R file?

Comment: `"Never import the R file"`. totally wrong. You need to import the classes you use, that's how java works, unless you are in the same package these are.

Comment: @artworkadシ under gen folder what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can import R files, they are sometimes needed to be imported, e.g. when you define them in a library and you need to use them in the package that uses that library.

You can also use full names - this may make the code more clear even if longer.